# I can't quite understand the following code in js, perhaps someone will enlighten me

Tags: javascript, destructuring

The following code will output 0,2 to the console:

```
let a =2, b= 0;
( () => {
[a,b]=[b,a];
}) ();
console.log(a,b)
```

I think I kinda understand what's happening here:

```
() => {
[a,b]=[b,a];
}
```

an arrow function and destructuring to exchange the places of the variables. But why it has to be enclosed in parentheses and also have additional () in the end to work is beyond my understanding.
I tried reading MDN on arrow function expressions to no avail. What exactly is happening here?

Comment: There's not really any point to it here. May as well be `let a =2, b= 0; [a,b]=[b,a]; console.log(a,b)`

Comment: The code inside () is considered an anonymous function. So every variable declared there with "let" will not be accessible outside.